# How can I deploy a spring-boot application on Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: java, iis, spring-boot

I have a Springboot application that I've more or less completed and is running smoothly on my local host.

I also have a Windows server that I can now begin to play with. I've figured out that when I hit this server with its IP address in my browser it shows a Hello World page from Windows IIS at this location:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\iisstart.html
```

Can I simply copy and paste the entire contents of my current springboot application into this folder and expect it to work? Can I copy and paste a JAR file? I have been unable to find a clear answer as to how to deploy my application to my server so that other users can access it. What should I do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Spring Boot first create a ‘fully executable’ jar with Maven use the following plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <executable>true</executable>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

With Gradle

```
springBoot {
    executable = true
}
```

Go to application directory (Where you have to install web app in system )

Paste Spring boot bundled jar (build using `mvn package`)

Go to current path via command prompt and just type `java -jar ...jarName.jar`.(eg. java -jar custstomerService.jar)

**Note:**

When a fully executable jar is run, it uses the jar’s directory as the working directory.

This is only for spring boot with bundled web server jar deployment not for war

[More details](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications)

Comment: I'm a little confused. When I find the .jar on my local machine, do I just put it in the IIS wwwroot directory on my Windows 2012 R2 server and the website will just work after I run it?

Comment: @santafebound the directory choice is yours like any ware in your system best choice outside IIS server directory because java and .Net different platform

Comment: Okay but so what you're saying is that fat .jar literally contains everything I need to run my website? If I just run the jar file anywhere on my system the web app will be accessible at my server's IP?

Comment: @santafebound yes with ip and port configurable in application.properties if not configure take system ip and 8080 port

Comment: Yup, I've got that sorted out. I just need to find a way to transfer this jar file to my VM so I can confirm that your instructions work.

Comment: Please edit your answer so I can upvote you. Somebody downvoted you. Also, it works. But it required the Tomcat port in the IP address. This isn't related to my question, though.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the instructions above do not work on my virtualized server. Whilst running the 'uber-jar' will start the Tomcat instance and serve the page up, it will only do so whilst the user is logged into the VM. If your VM has any auto-timeout rules set for users then the site will no longer be live once you are kicked. As far as I can tell it is necessary to setup your spring boot application as a windows service so that it persists.