# How to host Spring Boot Executable jar file on IIS using Undertow server?

Tags: java, spring-boot, windows-services, iis-8, host

I am trying to deploy my Spring Boot application as windows service on client server. My POM file uses Undertow server instead of tomcat. I am able to do this stuff using Winsw and it works fine on server on localhost. The actual challenge is hosting it on IIS, I tried to bind it using https for port 443 but couldn't get the API's working. Any leads will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is your issue solved?
If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.
If your issue still exists then try to refer the solution given by the community members.
If then also you have any further questions then let us know about it.
We will try to provide further suggestions to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use AJP, i.e. the change [`.addHttpListener(8080, "localhost")`](http://undertow.io/javadoc/2.0.x/io/undertow/Undertow.Builder.html#addHttpListener-int-java.lang.String-) to [`.addAjpListener(8009, "localhost")`](http://undertow.io/javadoc/2.0.x/io/undertow/Undertow.Builder.html#addAjpListener-int-java.lang.String-) then install the [ISAPI redirector for Microsoft IIS](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html), which is a proxy that allows IIS to forward the request to a backend web server using the AJP protocol.

Although the above link to the ISAPI redirector is to a Tomcat site, the redirector doesn't really care what server is on the other end of the AJP connection, so it doesn't have to be Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the spring-boot-maven-plugin. The plugin is automatically added to pom.xml once the Spring project is created via [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) as a Maven project.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

package the application in a single jar file, run the maven command `mvn package` under the project directory. This will package the application inside an executable jar file with all its dependencies(including the embedded servlet container — if its a web application). To run the jar file, use the following standard JVM command `java -jar <jar-file-name>.jar`.

[How can I deploy a spring-boot application on Windows Server 2012 R2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42947251/how-can-i-deploy-a-spring-boot-application-on-windows-server-2012-r2)